# Silverlight HyperlinkButton styles in custom control

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a strange styling problem that I cannot figure out.
What I want to achieve is that HyperlinkButtons in datagrid cells are styled with an underline when the mouse hovers the link.

I have one column where I declare the HyperlinkButton element in XAML like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonStyle}" DataContext="{Binding}" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding DguNr}" Click="DgunrHyperlinkButtonClick" />
```

This works fine - the link is styled as I want.
In another column, I need to display n number of HyperlinkButtons based on some information in the bound element. Hence I have created a usercontrol that will render 0..n Hyperlinkbuttons. The control is declared in XAML like this:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="True">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <bc:BoreholePlantGridColumn Plants="{Binding Plants, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The code behind for the control looks like this:

```
public partial class BoreholePlantGridColumn : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BoreholePlantGridColumn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(BoreholePlantGridColumn_Loaded);
    }

    void BoreholePlantGridColumn_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var borehole = (SelectableBoring)this.DataContext;
        foreach(var p in borehole.Plants)
        {
            // <HyperlinkButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding DguNr}" Click="DgunrHyperlinkButtonClick" />
            var button = new HyperlinkButton();
            button.Content = p.PlantId;
            button.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["HyperlinkButtonStyle"];
            button.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            var url = String.Format(Common.Constants.Url.GeusPlantLinkTemplate, p.PlantId);
            button.NavigateUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            button.TargetName = "_blank";
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(button);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlantsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(Anlaeg), typeof(BoreholePlantGridColumn), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChanged)));

    public IList<Anlaeg> Plants
    {
        get { return (IList<Anlaeg>)this.GetValue(PlantsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(PlantsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myUC = (BoreholePlantGridColumn)obj;
        var newValue = (IList<Anlaeg>)e.NewValue;


    }
}
```

This works almost as expected; the linkbuttons(s) are rendered with the correct color - but there is not displayed an underline text when the mouse hovers the link.
I do not understand why the underline is displayed in the hyperlinkbutton that is declared directly in XAML but not in the hyperlink that is rendered in code-behind. Can someone please help me on this?

I have used the hyperlinkbutton styling from this thread:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141392/how-can-i-add-an-underline-to-a-hyperlinkbutton-in-silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

I just use the Following Code

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding EncyclopediaList}" HorizontalContentAlignment ="Stretch" Margin="5,0" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" Command="{Binding ViewArticlePageCommand, Source={StaticResource EncyclopediaViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ServerEncyclopediaID}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

No need to Style the HyperlinkButton its Works perfectly in My Case Add the Underline and Make it bold when Mouse move over it.

Comment: Yes - it works fine for me too when declared in XAML but not added from code-behind.

Comment: Remove the Style you just give to the Hyperlink button when you create the Hyperlink button Dynamically. Hyperlink button will automatically get the styles. Hope this help.