# Remove Underline From HyperLinkButton XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, hyperlink, underline

I need to remove underlines from links, on HyperLinkButton on XAML.

I tried set property 'TextDecoration' but this property is not recognized.
(This is for an application, Win10)

Someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the property isn't `TextDecoration` but is `TextDecorations`

Comment: Yep, [TextBlock.TextDecorations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textdecorations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and you'll want to set it to {x:Null}

Comment: <HyperlinkButton Content="test" TextBlock.Decorations="{x:Null} NavigateUri="http://www.google.com"/>

Right? If yes, this is not correct.

Comment: Replace `TextBlock.Decorations` with just `TextDecorations` like @trjast pointed out and you should be good. Oh, and if you want someone to get notified of a response, remember to put @theirname at the beginning of the comment.

Comment: @Chris W., thanks for your reply but the property "TextDecorations" not showed in Hyperlinkbutton properties.

Comment: @fipcurren88 you're going to need to use a textblock as the content for the Hyperlinkbutton if you want to set the TextDecorations property, since it only applies to text blocks. For an example, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3143406/2392442)

Comment: Yea, you can look at the default style template for the HyperlinkButton for windows store apps and see if they're using a ContentPresenter or a TextBlock in there or what. If it's a ContentPresenter then they probably just have a Rectangle in there faking the underline that you could del from the template.